# jQuery Masonry and media queries - reload masonry

Tags: jquery, media-queries, jquery-masonry

i have my site designed with media queries to cover different-sized layouts.  i have masonry organizing a bunch of floats at the full-size width, no problem.  at the mobile widths, all the floats, unfloat and just stack on top of each other.  so i only need to re-run masonry when the site resizes to the tablet layout when 768px <= width <= 1000px.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

    $(document).ready(function($){

        $('ul.xoxo').masonry({ singleMode: true, itemSelector: '.widgetcontainer'  });

        //If the User resizes the window, adjust the #container height
        $(window).bind("resize", resizeWindow);
        function resizeWindow( e ) {
            var newWindowWidth = $(window).width();

            if(newWindowWidth<1008){
                $('ul.xoxo').masonry();
            } else {
                $('ul.xoxo').masonry();
            }
        }

    });

/* ]]> */
</script>
```

which doesn't work for me yet, but also i don't want it running on all resizes... just at the break points.

Comment: Possibly because you're doing the exact same thing for both if and else?

Comment: that's true.  i need it to run again whenever it passes a certain screen width (in my example 1008) and with an adjusted column size depending on whether it is larger or smaller than 1008

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a better solution for what i was trying to do is called Isotope, which works better on resize

http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

Comment: Be warned isotope is not under the same license, it's not opensource: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/license.html

Answer (score 5):

You can use Masonary's isResizable option for these cases.

```
  $container.masonry({
    itemSelector: '.box',
    isResizable: true
  });
```